# How to retrieve the XML file which is under the project folder

Tags: c#, xml

I having an XML file and that file is under the Documents folder. 
If I actually give the entire path in C# then I am able to retrieve the XML values, but if I give the project path then it is not getting the values.

For example:

```
string fileNamePath=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLDocPath"].ToString() + fileName;
m_xmld.Load(fileNamePath);
```

It is throwing a runtime error.

Comment: the runtime error is "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents\test.xml"
actually my xml is in d: drive but it is taking as "c:\"

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLDocPath"]`? Where is it defined?

It looks like you've simply got that set to the wrong value.

Also you should use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to build up your full filename as this takes care of adding delimiters for you.

Comment: i configured the XML Document path in Web.config folder and here i need to give the project path like the "/projectname/documents/file.xml"
like this .
if i have in d: drive but it is taking as c:

Comment: @Vara - If you need it to be in D: you're going to have to specify it explicitly.

Comment: so why i required this if i kept as "D:" explicitly if i deployed the site and again i have to change the directory path each and every time
so for that reason i am asking

Comment: @Vara - Without the drive letter the code will assume that it's the drive of the current working directory which is usually where the application starts from. Is the application on D:?